# Jenkins Groovy script and dynamodb query using aws cli not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, groovy, amazon-dynamodb, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to retrieve items from dynamodb table in Active Choices Reactive Parameter.
The groovy script I am trying is -

```
def command = 'aws dynamodb query \
                --table-name release  \
                --key-condition-expression "Component = :a" \
                --expression-attribute-values \'{":a": { "S": "information" } }\' \
                --projection-expression \'Revision\' --output text | tail -n +2 |cut -f2'
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()              

def output = proc.in.text
def exitcode= proc.exitValue()
def error = proc.err.text

if (error) {
    println "Std Err: ${error}"
    println "Process exit code: ${exitcode}"
    return exitcode
}


return output.split()
```

Somehow, this is not working.
I understand that groovy doesn't allow " but how this can be achieved for dynamodb queries?